# newSpellCheckerSession always returns null

Tags: android, spell-checking

I'm trying to hook into the built in Android spell checking service on my Note tablet.  When I call

```
    final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager) getSystemService(
            Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);
    spellCheck = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null, this, true);
```

spellCheck is always null.  The device is 4.1.2, so it ought to at least have the word suggestion capability.  Has anyone used this service directly to give me some pointers?  The web is very sparse about this, since it usually comes through the keyboard.

Comment: how did you get suggestions words? this matter is being a puzzle for me!

Comment: Maybe the solution is to create you own spellchecker service? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html

Comment: It might have worked, but Samsung removed even the option to select one from settings. Possibly if one was installed it would reappear. But that's a lot of work to do well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And I found the answer-  Samsung disabled the feature on this model.  So I'm either going to have to force users to install 2 APKs and jump some hoops, or include the library as source in my apk.

Comment: I wonder, did you ever find a way around this or just exclude the functionality for these devices? Because there are a few devices where this functionality is missing.

Comment: I excluded the functionality.  One could, theoretically install it as 2 apks, or possibly grab an open source version from the AOSP and use it directly.

Comment: @GabeSechan Very helpful. How did you determine that this service is disabled on specific models? I have ran into the same issue and I am trying to asses how many of our users would be affected by this based on their devices.

Comment: Most Samsung devices have it disabled, at least 2 years ago. Not sure about now

Answer (score 2):

You may want to set the local explicitly, and set last parameter to false, as it checks the active locales on the device.

```
final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager) getSystemService(
        Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);
spellCheck = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, Local.ENGLISH, this, false);
```

Comment: This actually works. For some reason some Samsung devices wouldn't let you have access to the Spelling Settings (you can't event find that on the device settings). So it will be always better to specify locale. 
Preferably add the option to select language on the settings and use that as locale.

Comment: It didn't work for me (testing on Samsung Galaxy A5 - pre-2016 model).