# Android Spell Checker Service not working

Tags: android, spell-checking

I am trying to write a simple Spell Checker Client for Android based on HelloSpellChecker sample, and for some reason on different Samsung tablets, it does not work - newSpellCheckerSession returns null for whatever locale I specify. On an Asus Nexus 7 it works fine. They are all running 4.4.

I researched a lot and found some posts of people using Samsung devices not getting the red error marks for misspelled words. Some solutions suggested rooting the device and changing some hardcoded values there.

I really don't want to root or depend on a rooting for solution for this.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863274/newspellcheckersession-always-returns-null) with a solution that somebody says it works, but it is not for me.

Anybody has an idea how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code -- the smallest example that will demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices do not support spellcheck because they have Samsung keyboard input type and other devices have Google keyboard.